# Debezium SQL Server Connector - "Couldn't obtain database name"

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm trying to set up a Debezium SQL Server Connector against a SQL Server instance that is controlled by DBAs at my workplace. I've been able to start up Zookeeper and Kafka Server without issue, and Kafka Connect itself works with sample Connectors, but when attempting to start a Debezium SQL Server Connector instance I've been getting the error "Couldn't obtain database name".

```
[2022-07-12 16:36:04,269] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:117)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):
Unable to connect. Check this and other connection properties. Error: Couldn't obtain database name
```

Here is my debezium config:

```
name=Dbz-SqlServer-connector
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector
database.hostname=MyDbHost
database.port=1433
database.user=MyUsername
database.password=MyPassword
database.dbname=MyDatabase
database.server.name=MyDbHost
table.include.list=dbo.CdcTest
database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
database.history.kafka.topic=dbhistory.CdcTest
```

I've tried this in a .properties file passed to a standalone Connect instance, and as  a JSON POST to a distributed Connect instance. I have tried all of the same steps on both my local Windows machine as well as on a linux VM, with the same results.

Confluent and Docker are not options for me in this situation.

for SQL Server login credentials, I am using a local account on the SQL Server instance that does have access to the database in question. I found the source code for debezium's connectors on [their github](https://github.com/debezium/debezium) and was able to find that specific error message within the code:

```
    private static final String GET_DATABASE_NAME = "SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = ?";

...

    public String retrieveRealDatabaseName(String databaseName) {
        try {
            return prepareQueryAndMap(GET_DATABASE_NAME,
                    ps -> ps.setString(1, databaseName),
                    singleResultMapper(rs -> rs.getString(1), "Could not retrieve exactly one database name"));
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't obtain database name", e);
        }
    }
```

I'm not completely familiar with Java but it appears that basically something is going wrong when the connector is trying to run "SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'MyDatabase'". When I run this against the database myself, logged in with the same account I'm using, it seems to work just fine, so I'm really not sure where to go from here. It is fair to say that since I'm not in full control of the SQL Server environment that I'm using, there may be some permissions issues that I'm not aware of, but from what I'm able to test it seems like it should be working.

I would greatly appreciate any help at all, whether just suggestions on settings/configs to check or a full-blown solution.

Thank you!

Update: I've built a simple console app to run that sys.databases query against MyDbHost, master database, as the relevant account, and it's working just fine so I feel like that confirms that my connection info is correct and account permissions are also correct. Seems like this is an issue within the Debezium connector.

Comment: [Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql#permissions) are conditionally required to select from `sys.databases`. Does the logon being used by Debezium meet any of the listed criteria?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning The logon I'm using has the public role but I'll have to check with a DBA to find out if "VIEW ALL DATABASES" permission has been revoked from public, that does seem likely. If I run a query in SSMS using the logon and pointing to DB master, sys.databases returns MyDatabase properly which implies to me that it should work, though I know things can work a little different in SSMS than they would with other connections.

Comment: I would also think that "The database to which the caller is connected can always be viewed in sys.databases." would mean it should work, but I guess that depends on if Debezium is connecting to the specified database before making that call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my problem was a mistake in the connector's config setting. I misunderstood which specific pieces of data to put into database.hostname and database.server.name, and one I corrected those fields the connector works.